# How do you say “Fuck + noun”?

Tags: langage-informel, jurons, langage-des-jeunes

How would you translate things like:

• Fuck studying!

• Fuck that!

• Fuck him!

• Fuck your ideas!

Basically they mean that you want nothing to do with it, you hate it, it’s really annoying, etc. (but a very vulgar way to say it!)

Comment: https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/fuck has some promising suggestions.

Answer (score 11):

The verb *[niquer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/niquer)* matches quite well the various meanings of *fuck* and belongs to the same register.

> *Fuck studying!* :  Nique les études !
>
> *Fuck that!* : Nique cette merde !
>
> *Fuck him!* : Nique sa race !
>
> *Fuck your ideas!* : Nique tes idées !

In this kind of sentences, *niquer* is however less widely used than *fuck* in English, and more popular among younger people, especially urban/suburban ones.

A more mainstream expression is *j'emmerde* as suggested by [madlozoz](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/37329/1109).

Comment: Totally the one that I would use on an everyday basis. Although using "F*ck" itself in French is quite common too !

Comment: I agree ! *Nique* matches it perfectly, I am even surprised that the other answers got so many upvotes being such a poor translation "Merdes aux études" in the answer of LPH, it's like being mad but trying to still be polite, obviously not the point of saying "Fuck something".

Answer (score 7):

• Fuck studying! : Merde aux études !
• Fuck that! : Merde à tout ça !
• Fuck him! : Qu'il aille se faire foutre !
• Fuck your ideas! : Merde à vos/tes idées !

Answer (score 7):

Au Québec uniquement (pour l'emploi usuel du mot anglais directement) :

> *Fuck* les études ! 
>   *Fuck that*/ça !
>  Qu'il mange de la *marde* / qu'il aille chez le diable ! 
>   *Fuck* tes idées !

À mon avis l'emploi du mot *fuck* en français du Québec est perçu comme bien moins vulgaire que ça ne l'est en langue anglaise...

Answer (score 5):

Dans un registre que j'utiliserais plus spontanément :

• Fuck studying! = Putain d'études !

• Fuck that! = Merde !

• Fuck him! = Enculé !

• Fuck your ideas! = Va te faire enculer !

Answer (score 4):

I would use "j'emmerde" in each case but "fuck that":

- Fuck studying! = J'emmerde les études!
- Fuck that! = Rien à branler! (there are 1000 other way to express this)
- Fuck him! = Je l'emmerde!
- Fuck your ideas! = J'emmerde tes idées (it would be more natural to say "je t'emmerde, toi et tes putain d'idées")

You can also replace "j'emmerde" par "j'encule" like in this <s>piss</s> piece of poetry

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wz_YbtVnYcw

Answer (score 1):

Fuck studying! - Les études, j'en ai rien à foutre!

Fuck that! - J'en ai rien à foutre!

Fuck him! - Qu'il aille se faire foutre!

Fuck your ideas! - Tes idées, j'en ai rien à foutre!

Here's a recent example of the use of *foutre* from France Inter : …donc, les leçons de Charline, j'en ai rien à foutre! (https://youtu.be/-ODoIqbqST4, at 1'04''), So, fuck Charline's lessons!

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est certainement pas usuel mais ça l'a été et puis je l'aime bien : **Au diable!**

Au diable les études!, Au diable tes idées!, Qu'il aille au diable!

Qui m'offre aussi la possibilité de traduire un plus difficile mais plus courant FTS! :

Au diable cette merde!